# Directed galleries of the building of type $\widetilde{A}_{n}$

Tags: coxeter-groups, p-adic-groups, buildings

Let $X$ be the affine building of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_{p})$. We call oreinetd chamber of $X$ every sequence $\overrightarrow{C}=(s_1,...,s_n)$ of vertices such that $C=\{s_1,...,s_n\}$ is a chamber of $X$. If $\overrightarrow{C}=(s_1,...,s_n)$ and $\overrightarrow{C'}=(s'_1,...,s'_n)$ are two oriened chambers of $X$, we say that $\overrightarrow{C}$ is directly linked to $\overrightarrow{C'}$ if :
$$\forall~1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1,~s'_i=s_{i+1}.$$
We call directed gallery every sequence $(\overrightarrow{C_0},...,\overrightarrow{C_m})$ of oriented chambers such that for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant m-1$, $\overrightarrow{C_i}$ is directly linked to $\overrightarrow{C_{i+1}}$ and $\overrightarrow{C_i}\neq\overrightarrow{C_{i+1}}$. Obviously, if $(\overrightarrow{C_0},...,\overrightarrow{C_m})$ is a directed gallery of $X$, then the corresponding sequence of non-oriented chambers $(C_0,...,C_m)$ is a non-stuttering gallery of $X$.

I want to prove that the non-stuttering gallery $(C_0,...,C_m)$ corresponding to the directed gallery $(\overrightarrow{C_0},...,\overrightarrow{C_m})$ is necessarily a minimal gallery of $X$ and then it lies a same apartment of $X$. Thank you in advance for your help.